# Not able to executing watch method of gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I am using Restclient form my rails4 application and executing the post method for watch method of gmail,it needs topic and label as its parameter 
   This is my code

RestClient.post "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/#{email}/watch?access_token=#{token}", {"topicName" => "projects/project_name/topics/my_topic","label" => "INBOX" , "Content-type" => "application/json"}

its giving me bad request , can any one suggest me whats the right way ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the issue is here. Can your update the question with full request and response of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have done this in proper order

1. Enabled pubsub in google developer console
2. Create topic
3. Create pubsub subscription
4. grant publish rights

Comment: ya, I have done it in the same order, and I am making the watch request and its not working, Should I use some else then rest client to call the watch request @pratasJ